# Get clicked position on a transformed Imageview

Tags: android, click, android-imageview, transformation, tap

I'm using the `Almeros Gesture Detector` ([Link](https://github.com/Almeros/android-gesture-detectors)) and I'm trying to extend it, in order to get the clicked position when i click on the transformed imageview. As example i have anothe library, the `ChrisBanes PhotoView` ([Link](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)).

I Tryied to combine them, but they are to different and i'm not able to.

Suppose i need to display the name of the state when one is tapped. How can i get the relative (or absolute?) position?